# How can I validate time if there is already an existing one?

Tags: mysql

Hello i have one table name tbl_Clock it's have one field name Clock. this is some example of my table :

### | Clock |

| 08.00-09.40 |
| 09.40-10.00 |
| 10.00-11.40 |

And here is my question.

if i want to check if there is already existing clock, then i just execute this code :

```
select * from tbl_Clock where substring(Clock,1,5) >= '08.00' AND substring(Clock,7,5) <= '09.40'
```

it's work if there already exact same time if I execute above code, and i can prevent data to be saved.

but what if I input a time like 09.40-10.50 or 08.00-10.00, it's still can be saved even though there is already a time existing between them. Anyone know what is the best way to validate this one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to check if there is any intersection between the time slots you have and any newly entered time slots.

As a start, please store the start and end time as TIME in the DB, not as a string. I would be better for many reasons. The start time will be a column named `START` and the end time column will be `END`.

Second, there is already an answer about checking any intersections, I will share the link once I found it. The general check would be

```
WHERE START <= :end AND END >= :start
```

So, if you want to check if `09:40` to `10:00` has any intersection with already existing records, then the query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE START <= '10:00:00' AND END  >= '09:40:00'
```

This should return the first three records in your question, indicating that the time slot is already intersecting with existing time slots.

Comment: nice. but it if i input 10:00 - 10:50 , it still can be saved to database even though there is already 10:00-10.40. any solution ?

Comment: Did you try my answer? :) is it pretty hard to check it by eyes only. For `start = 10:00 and end = 10:50 `. the condition will match for `(10:00 - 10:40)`  as  `10:00 <= 10:50  AND 10:40 >= 10:00)`. Just give it a try!

Comment: ah yes that's is true, and here rise another problem i try input 08:30 for the start and 10:10 for the end. there should already an existing time between this time. but it still can be saved to database. any solution ? there is already 08.00-09.40, so it should be impossible for 08.30-10.10 can be saved too

Comment: For `start = 08:30` and `end = 10:10` . the condition will match for `(08:00 - 09:40)`      because `08:00 <= 10:10 AND 09:40 >= 08:30`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the key "check if there is any intersection between the time slots". i started google for it and i got the perfect solution even for the single column using `SELECT * FROM tbl_clock where ('08.30' between substring(clock,1,5) and substring(clock,7,5)) or ('10.10' between substring(clock,1,5) and substring(clock,7,5))` . great man i give you my thumbs

Comment: sadly its not return anything at all. just empty field. are you already trying it ?

Comment: wait i am a bit confused in your explaining... i mean yes `08.00` is `<= 08.30' but `09.40` is not `>= 10.10` right ?? so of course it will return empy field

Comment: It is confusing, but solid and covers all cases. the check is `08:00 <= 10:10 AND 09:40 >= 08:30`.  which is true.